# How to get properly all queue messages from RabbitMQ in Spring?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, mqtt, stomp, spring-websocket

I am using Spring, Spring-Websocket, STOMP for my application, and RabbitMQ as broker. I need to log all messages going through RabbitMQ to Postgresql tables. 
I know that I can write @MessageMapping in Spring and log there, but my problem is that some clients talk to RabbitMQ directly through MQTT protocol, and Spring does not support it yet (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12581). Moreover browser clients talk through Spring to RabbitMQ using STOMP protocol.

RabbitMQ allows to track all messages using Firehose tracer. How to properly listen to amq.rabbitmq.trace topic from Spring? Or do I need to write separate Java app as consumer?

Comment: i don't understand you need to do it with spring. just configure rabbitmq to do it..

Comment: I need to write to DB to different tables

Comment: hmm.. then IMO you need an application to do it. you can certainly also put this consumer among other consumers. the docu from rabbitmq describes pretty well (https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html), have a look, if your question is if spring amqp has this feature out of box, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Spring AMQP](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/) is for you!

You *bind* some custom `queue` to to that `amq.rabbitmq.trace` with appropriate pattern (e.g. `publish.#`) and configure `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to receive messages from that queue.

It can be done even with pretty simple config: `@EnableRabbit` and `@RabbitListener` on some POJO method. Anyway the `Binding` `@Bean` must be there to attache your queue to that exchange.

Comment: Well. I'm not good in the Spring WebSocket Broker Relay and not sure that it will work, but you can try to `subscribe` like this: `/topic/exchange/amq.rabbitmq.trace/publish.#`

Comment: Is it ok to use AMQP to listen to Rabbit, and Stomp Broker relay to serve clients in one application?

Comment: Exactly! Spring STOMP support just takes care about WebSocket part in your applicaiton, but with Spring AMQP you do hard work around Broker queues and others.